# Portable hard drive - bad sectors blocks fails on backup

Tags: data-recovery, cp

I have a 2TB portable hard drive from Western Digital that I have used over the years. 
I use it on my home server to for NFS streaming. I have noticed recently while streaming some content it fails to play and first thought it was my server configuration but after further investigating the issue I have found it is my NTFS partition on the hard drive that was faulty.

I have used `rsync`, and `cp` to copy the content but I get `read/write io failure` when trying to copy over the content. I thought about making a disk image with `dd` but as the hard drive is 2TB thats a very large image and all I have are 2TB hard drives out here with me.

What is my best option for backing up all this content without having files skipped over because of `read write io fails`?